# Proper format for this equation

Tags: formatting, equations

I have this equation that is slightly too long and want to split it somehow nicely, unfortunately I am incapable of doing this right. Could anybody help me with this?

```
\begin{align}
\mathbb{T}(\sinh^2(\theta))(t) &= \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \left(  +\frac{|b_n|^2}{4}  + \sum_{m=|n|}^{n+3} \left( \operatorname{Re} \left(a_n^* a_m e^{i(n-m)t}\sqrt{n+\frac{7}{2}} \sqrt{m+\frac{7}{2}} \right) \begin{pmatrix}
n+2 & 4 & m  \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}^2 \right) \\
\end{align}
```

Comment: You know the drill: Post an entire MWE (minimum working example), not just a code snippet. In particular, since you say that the equation is "slightly too long", it would be important to know stuff like the width of the text block, the font size in use, and any nonstandard fonts (if any) you may be using.

Comment: Its exactly one line, so the equation number does not fit in this line anymore. Hence, no matter where I split this equation, it should be alright. The problem is that if I split, I get two equation numbers, but I only want one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A too long formula with several terms in it is difficult to read, particularly when it must be split across lines and there are no “good” break points like in this case. So I believe the better strategy is to remove the most complicated term and set it apart:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{T}(\sinh^2(\theta))(t) =
  \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
  \biggl( \frac{|b_n|^2}{4}  +
    \sum_{m=|n|}^{n+3} F(a;m,n)
       \begin{pmatrix}
       n+2 & 4 & m  \\
       0 & 0 & 0
       \end{pmatrix}^{\!2}\,
  \biggr)
\end{equation}
where
\[
F(a;m,n)=\operatorname{Re}
  \left(
    a_n^* a^{}_m e^{i(n-m)t}\sqrt{n+\frac{7}{2}} \sqrt{m+\frac{7}{2}}\,
  \right)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `align` for single line displays. Look carefully to see where `\,` and `\!` have been inserted; they provide a thin space and the negative of it, respectively; tiny, but noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a solution (some text probably omitted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
&\mathbb{T}(\sinh^2(\theta))(t)\nonumber \\
&\qquad = \frac{2}{3} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} 
\Biggl( +\frac{|b_n|^2}{4}  + \sum_{m=|n|}^{n+3} 
\Biggl( \operatorname{Re} 
\Biggl(a_n^* a_m e^{i(n-m)t}\sqrt{n+\frac{7}{2}} \sqrt{m+\frac{7}{2}} 
\Biggr) % here?
\Biggr)\times\nonumber\\
& \qquad \times\begin{pmatrix}
n+2 & 4 & m  \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}^2 \Biggr) 
\end{align}

 \end{document}
```

[image]